# Block brute-force on server with http auth behind cloudflare proxies

Tags: http, authentication, iptables, brute-force

My server is behind Cloudflare proxies. I have configured simple http authentication to restrict access to some server resources. I'm trying to block brute-force attacks on http auth with fail2ban.

The problem is that all the traffic comes through Cloudflare servers (other sources are blocked), so I can't simply block the real IP of an attacker. Is it possible to run a firewall that would use HTTP headers to find the real IP address of the attacker, and block traffic originating from that IP (before it goes through Cloudflare)?

Comment: Have you tried contacting cloud-flare?  If they're your proxy service provider, they've probably a) heard this question before and b) have a solution already implemented that you can use.

Answer (score 2):

While this is a little old and missed, you can restore the visitor IPs to your log by installing something like [mod_cloudflare](https://cloudflare.zendesk.com/forums/21318827-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-to-my-server-logs-).